# Login/Logout onclick form toggle

Tags: jquery, authentication, toggle, form-submit, logout

Building on this demo:
http://red-team-design.com/simple-and-effective-dropdown-login-box/

I'm building a login/logout onclick form:
https://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/h9v2epfr/

```
<div id="who">
  <ul>
    <li id="login">
      <a id="login-trigger" href="#">
        Log in <span>&#x25BC;</span>
      </a>
      <div id="login-content">
        <form id="loginform">
          <fieldset id="inputs">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input id="username" type="text" autofocus placeholder="Your username" required>
            <label for="password">Password</label>   
            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Your password" required>
          </fieldset>
         <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="submit" id="insubmit" value="Log in"  class="logit">
            <input type="button" id="incancel" value="Cancel"  class="forgetit">
            <!-- <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Keep me signed in</label> -->
          </fieldset>
         </form>
      </div>                     
    </li>
    <li id="logout">
      <a id="logout-trigger" href="#">
        Log out <span>&#x25BC;</span>
      </a>
      <div id="logout-content">
        <form id="logoutform">
         <fieldset id="actions">
            <input id="name" type="text" value="Firstname Lastname (username)" readonly>
            <input type="submit" id="outsubmit" value="Log out" class="logit">
            <input type="reset" id="outcancel" value="Cancel"  class="forgetit">
            <!-- <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Keep me signed in</label> -->
          </fieldset>
         </form>
      </div>                     
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm having trouble determining why it behaves differently on the first submit, than on subsequent login/logouts.  In Chrome and IE (but not in Firefox) the login submit button submits the toggle twice on the FIRST try, but afterwards it toggles correctly.

I'm also having some trouble controlling the toggle arrow and active class when going back and forth.

Can anyone help me to straighten this out?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution... I'm sharing it here in case someone else is interested.

https://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/h9v2epfr/

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#login-trigger').click(function(){
            $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('active');                          
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
              else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
            });
          $('#logout-trigger').click(function(){
            $(this).next('#logout-content').slideToggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('active');                          
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
              else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
            }); 
            $('#loginform').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#login, #logout').toggle();
                $('#loginform').find('input:text').val('');
                $('#loginform').find('input:password').val('');
            });
            $('#logoutform').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#login, #logout').toggle();
                $('#login-content').hide();
                $('#login-trigger').toggleClass('active');                          
                $('#login-trigger').find('span').html('&#x25BC;');                 
            }); 
            $('#incancel').click(function(){
                $(':input','#loginform')
                    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
                    .val('');
                $('#login-content').slideToggle();
                $('#login-trigger').toggleClass('active');                          
                $('#login-trigger').find('span').html('&#x25BC;');
            });
            $('#outcancel').click(function(){
                $(':input','#loginform')
                    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
                    .val('');
                $('#logout-content').slideToggle();
                $('#logout-trigger').toggleClass('active'); 
                $('#logout-trigger').find('span').html('&#x25BC;');                                         
            });                             
        });
```